# Importing GPO backup into a different domain fails with "No backups found!" error

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I'm trying to make a backup of a GPO in one domain (just contains a couple registry key entries) and import it into another domain. The second domain is completely separate, it's at a different site with no shared trust.

I've followed the steps in articles like [this one from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln283515/windows-server-how-to-import-a-group-policy-objects-settings-into-another-group-policy-object?lang=en) but I always get the same "No backups found!" error no matter how I transfer the file (zipped or unzipped) or which folder I tell GPMC to search.

This GPO doesn't have any domain specific links so it seems like I shouldn't need a migration table setup to Import. Importing these GPO settings works fine on the domain controller it was backed up from, including into a new blank GPO.

I'm sure I must be missing something simple but most searches just come up with the standard steps I linked above. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Once you've copied your source GPO to a DC in the destination domain you need to import it's settings into a new GPO rather than trying to restore it. In the destination domain create a new, empty GPO then right click the new GPO and select "Import Settings", then follow the wizard.

[image]

Comment: Import is the function I've been trying from the start (like it says in the Dell guide I linked). Trying to import into empty and non-empty GPOs comes up with that same "No backups found!" error.